# Convert a json file to csv using shell script without using jq?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to convert a json file to csv using shell script *without* using jq. Is it possible?

Here is a json :

```
{
  "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
},
{
"id": "0002",
    "type": "donut2",
    "name": "Cake2",
    "ppu": 0.5522,
}
```

I don't want to use `jq`.

I want to store it in a csv file.

Comment: Good luck with that. Unless you can be sure that the file is formatted in a particular fashion, and there are no escape sequences that need to be processed specially, this will be difficult.

Comment: BTW, that's not valid JSON. If it's an array, it needs to have `[]` around it.

Comment: A shell script is not a good way to process *most* data; the shell's purpose is to run other commands that do the processing.

Comment: Can you make that code valid JSON and provide what the CSV output should look like?

Comment: `jq -r '.[] | [.id, .type, .name, .ppu] | @csv' foo.json > foo.csv` btw, assuming that's supposed to be an array of valid JSON objects.

Answer (score 13):

Bare-bones core-only perl one-liner version, to complement the python and ruby ones already given:

```
perl -MJSON::PP -0777 -nE '$,=","; say @$_{"id","type","name","ppu"} for @{decode_json $_}' input.json
```

A more robust one would use a more efficient non-core JSON parser and a CSV module to do things like properly quote fields when needed, but since your sample data doesn't include such fields I didn't bother. Can if requested.

---

And the unrequested `jq` version, because that really is the best approach whether you want it or not:

```
jq -r '.[] | [.id, .type, .name, .ppu] | @csv' input.json
```

Comment: Sometimes  I think I should really learn Perl. But then I see that syntax and... Naaaah! . Good answer though.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios If it was a standalone script and not a one liner meant for including in a shell script, I'd write it out more verbosely and with fewer shortcuts (but as is it's no worse than your Python and Ruby versions to my eye). You should learn perl; it's a nifty language.

Comment: Could you please explain the code. I want to write it according to the json file from the project I am working on.
perl -MJSON::PP -0777 -nE '$,=","; say @$_{"id","type","name","ppu"} for @{decode_json $_}' input.json  -- Doesnot work for me
Error msg on bash -- unexpected end of string while parsing JSON string, at character offset 82 (before ",\r\n{\r\n"id": "000...") at -e line 1.

Comment: @Shubham You need valid json; what you posted in the question isn't even if you wrap the objects in an array because of trailing commas in the objects. If that's what your real data is like, yeah, json parsers aren't going to accept it.

Comment: "errors": false,
 "messages": [],
 "requestId": null,
 "results": {
  "id": "2c91808a6d982ce2016dacd4119876eb",
  "inactive": false,
  "deleted": false,
  "lockVersion": null,
  "lastModifiedDate": null,
  "lastModifiedBy": "MONITORING SERVICE",
  "createdDate": 1570562642328,
  "createdBy": "admin"
}

there is more to this json,
please help me wih dynamic code.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not the tool to do this at all. But if for some reason you cannot install **jq**, you can simply use Python 3, which comes by default in most distros of Linux and in MacOS.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import json

objs=json.loads("""
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "donut2",
        "name": "Cake2",
        "ppu": 0.5522
    }
]
""")
for item in objs :
    print("{}{}{}{}{}{}{}".format(item['id'],",",item['type'],",",item['name'],",",item['ppu']))
```

If you do not have Python 3 either, you can then do it in Ruby, which also comes by default in most distros and MacOS :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'json'

content = '
[
    {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55
    },
    {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "donut2",
        "name": "Cake2",
        "ppu": 0.5522
    }
]
'

JSON.parse(content).each { |item| puts "#{item['id']},#{item['type']},#{item['name']},#{item['ppu']}" }
```

You can then redirect the output to a file :

```
script.rb > output.csv
```

And thats it.

Nevertheless, if you can be completely sure of the format of your input, you can do some bash magic, specially using awk. But as others also said, please don't do that.

Comment: The ruby can be simpler if you use the csv module as well: `require 'csv'; csv = CSV.new(STDOUT)` then `JSON.parse(content).each {|item| csv << item.values}` -- if the quotes should always be output for each field, then `csv = CSV.new(STDOUT, force_quotes: true)`